# border-radius gets weird when property has different values for corners on IE lte 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I'm applying border-radius for a few elements on my page, and in order to make it work on IE 6-8, I'm using [PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Check it out

[image: weirg bug o.O]

So as you can see, corners without values (or with values very different from each other) for border-radius, effect gets this weird.

Here's my code:

```
.cotacao {
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px 20px 1px 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px 20px 1px 20px;
  border-radius: 1px 20px 1px 20px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

And specific code for IE

```
.cotacao {
  behavior:url(/Assets/css/common/PIE.htc);
  position: relative !important;
}
```

What's going on? Is this bug related to the border thickness? And, if it is, is there a known workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the PIE 1.0 code. See https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/11

It's fixed in the 2.0 beta if you're willing to try that.

Comment: Thanks. If I can help anyone else, to create this effect, i have rounded all corners with same value and, in order to make top-left and bottom-right square, I used :before and :after with background images. Crappy, but it works.